# Как правильно составить html pattern

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В поле задаю тип `string`, и нужно чтобы проверялось на количество символов, максимально **7** штук, и чтобы можно было вводить только цифры в виде строки. Как это правильно реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name=km]").on("invalid", function() {
    this.setCustomValidity("Код материала должен содержать 7 цифр.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>Матеріал</label> <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{,7}" maxlength="7" class="input-sort" size="15px" name="km" id="km" align="middle" placeholder="Код">
  <button id="filtAccept">клёц</button>
</form>
```

Comment: указать `pattern="[0-9]{,7}"` ?

Comment: @Eleferen, а почему не ответ, а комментарий?

Comment: @Eleferen сделал правку в вопросе с вашим патерном, если нажать на кнопку при пустом поле выдаст сообщение, и после этого уже не будет принимать ни один вариант, а если вводить что-то в поле до того как нажал на кнопку, оно принимает и буквы и числа

Comment: убрал `required` ибо он тут лишний, а вот `pattern` почему-то не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pattern = [\d]{7}
```

или

```
pattern = [0-9]{7}
```

Comment: да такие `pattern ` работают, но сообщение не хочет выводиться мое

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: `[\d]` - что-то подозрительно, скобки же лишние...

Comment: @Qwertiy ничего подозрительного от копипаста остались, можно и без них )